# Image is not changing instantly

Tags: jquery, spring, servlets

I am changing **`img`** after successful response from server but it not changing instantly. I have to reload page to see new image.

After uploading photo to server Below is the URL that i am using for profile photo for userid `${userId}`. At the end of url i am using random number to avoid cache.

```
var img = "photohandler/fetchprofilepics/${userId}/profilePhoto/<%=new Random().nextInt()%>";
$(".profilePhoto").attr("src",img);
```

If paste same url in browser its showing image.

on server side in spring/servlet:

```
byte bytes[] = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];            
byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
var img = "photohandler/fetchprofilepics/${userId}/profilePhoto/<%=new Random().nextInt()%>";    
$(".profilePhoto").attr("src",img + '?'+ $.now());
```

This will remove cache issue i guess.

**EDIT:** ok i think your issue is that you think that server side code is still processed client side after page rendered...

Comment: @Satpal Why would it be better?

Comment: `<%=new Random().nextInt()%>` is already passing. it will change every time the image path

Comment: @Manish What does mean? Do you want it to give new randomized image or what? I'm really not sure to understand what you are expecting here. You should improve your question with a concrete example and more code context. Following your edited comment, are you sure a new path is generated each time you call this snippet? How do you call it then?

Comment: the problem was new path was always same to previous path

Comment: Ya because you are setting new path using server side code client side  which is then only processed once :)